# Is a surge a common-mode signal or a differential mode signal?

Tags: common-mode, surge

When a power circuit is powered up, there is always a surge because there is often a big capacitor connected to the input to filter the noise.

Is the surge a commom-mode signal or a differential-mode signal? I found someone used a common-mode inductance to reduce the surge, so is the surge a common-mode signal?

Comment: A surge caused by external events like a lightning strike can have common-mode components. A surge as you describe is purely differential-mode.

Comment: What do you mean by *power circuit is open*? Do you mean open-circuit?

Comment: A coupled inductor has four terminals and can be connected up in two different ways, not just common mode. The orientation of the dots matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you close a switch and there is an inrush current to charge the capacitor, equal amount of current will flow in supply wire and return wire. The surge is just a special case of spike compared to ordinary DC current to power a load.

Therfore, the surge current and DC current is differential current.

No, it is not a common mode signal.